# Object has parameters, but says it doesn't

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-3.5

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import time
tk = Tk()
tk.title("Pong")
tk.resizable(0,0)
tk.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
canvas = Canvas(tk, width=500, height=400, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
canvas.pack()
tk.update()
class Ball:
    def _init_(self, canvas, color):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.id = canvas.create_oval()
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 245, 100)

    def draw(self):
        pass
ball = Ball(canvas, 'red')
```

When I run the code, it returns the error:

```
TypeError: object() takes no parameters
```

Even though the object's parameters are defined.

Comment: `_init_` means nothing special in python. Needs two underscores on each side

Comment: You need two underscores on each side `__init__`

Comment: @cricket_007 that just brings up more errors

Comment: always show full error message (Traceback). Which line makes problem?

Comment: Well, that solved the mentioned error, which was a typo, therefore making this post off topic. You still have time to [edit], though

Comment: you have new error because `create_oval()` needs arguments.

Comment: which line is 19 and 14 ? SO doesn't display line numbers. Show full error message in question.

Comment: thank you @furas, this worked

Comment: see @falsetru answer - there is `create_oval()` with arguments

Comment: BTW, if you intend to animate this ball don't use `time.sleep`, that'll freeze the Tkinter mainloop. Instead, use the canvas widget's [`.after`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method) method. FWIW, I currently have a red ball bouncing around my screen. :)

Answer (score 3):

As others pointed out, you need to use double underscores in `__init__`,
and you missed arguments to `create_oval` call:

```
def __init__(self, canvas, color):  # <--- double underscores
    self.canvas = canvas
    self.id = canvas.create_oval(0, 0, 100, 100)  # <--- missing arguments
    self.canvas.move(self.id, 245, 100)
```